# Authorization for Deployed GAS Web Apps

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a basic deployed web app using Google Apps Script `HtmlService`. The goal of the app is to house and serve multiple html forms through templates, take the form data, record it, and email it to a designated email address. I've got the app code and UI to work smoothly but am having some service authorization errors:

One of the time saving features the web app employs is that the script uses `PropertiesService` to store some of each user's basic info so that they don't have to type it in every time. Now that I've deployed the Web app for testing, I am running into authorization errors.

When I personally try to run the script, I can access `PropertiesService` just fine, no hang ups. When a user who does not have the script shared with them tries to access the service, they get a notification to request access to the script itself, which I don't really want to give everyone in my team access to.

Has any one else tried to use authorized services for a deployed web app and run into similar problems? Do I need to add a special authorization function or script to my app to ensure end-users have the proper access? Should I try another method to accomplish saving/using individual user data?

Any advice would be welcomed.

Here's the code for storibg the user variables:

```
function processNewUserForm(formObject) {
  var newUserProperties = {
    first: formObject['firstName'],
    last: formObject['lastName'],
    emplid: formObject['EmplID'],
    email: user_email,
    workspace: formObject['Workspace'],
    team: formObject.team,
    username: formObject['Username'],
    computerTag: formObject['Computer Asset Tag']
  };

  try {
    userProperties.setProperties(newUserProperties, false);
  }
  catch(e) {
    sendErrorReport(e);
  }
}
```

Note: userProperties is defined globally as 
`var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();`

Comment: Good question.  Is the web app deployed to *execute the App as:*   - **User Accessing the Web App**  or as **Me**?  I'm assuming that you have it set to **User Accessing the Web App**.  I'm also assuming that you need to know who is using the form?

Comment: Yeah, it's deployed as User Accessing the Web App. I'd like to keep it this way because that means I can know for certain who is submitting a from (organizational sign in required). The other piece I'd like to keep is that the emails currently come from User accessing the web app rather than me. If I change the deployment to be from Me, all the emails would come from me.

Comment: Are you giving the users the /exec link and not the /dev? It seems like they are able to get up the point of receiving this error so that may not be the issue - your mention of having to share the script is why I ask...

Comment: The have the exec link. In fact the user actually receive the dialog to authorize. What ends up happening though is that any time the Web App calls a function that tries to access Script or User properties, google shows a request to share the document screen (the "Request Access" page you see when trying to access a google doc that's not shared). clicking the share link has the user ask for access to the GAS file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a lot of digging, but I actually found the root cause of the authorization problem. The server-side function I was calling actually contained several `Logger.log(var1iable)` references which was great for debugging but needed edit access to the script to run. I removed the  `Logger` references and the app is now functioning as expected.